# cannot remove [Unnamed:0] and NaN field data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xpath, webdriver

Cannot remove [Unnamed:0] and NaN fields data for the pd.DataFrame, and don't know why too many unwanted data coming from following coding, thanks !

```
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.fdmbenzinpriser.dk/searchprices/5/")

lines = [event.get_attribute('outerHTML') for event in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="sortabletable"]')]

df = pd.concat([pd.read_html(line)[0] for line in lines], ignore_index=True)
print df
print df.shape

driver.close()
display.stop()
```

Exist coding Output:

```
[                                           Unnamed: 0   Pris                        Adresse      Tidspunkt
0                                                 NaN   8.99       Odinsvej 2 4100 Ringsted  11 timer 55 m
1                                                 NaN   9.09   Sdr.Havnegade 3 6000 Kolding  14 timer 48 m
2                                                 NaN   9.09    Vestermarksvej 2 6600 Vejen  16 timer 35 m
3                                                 NaN  10.99  Bøsbrovej 92B 8940 Randers SV   21 timer 1 m
* Denne pris er indberettet af selskabet Indbe...    NaN
```

Expected Output:

```
Pris                               Adresse       Tidspunkt
8.99              Odinsvej 2 4100 Ringsted   8 timer 47 m
9.09          Sdr.Havnegade 3 6000 Kolding  11 timer 39 m
9.09           Vestermarksvej 2 6600 Vejen  13 timer 27 m
10.99            Kastanievej  2 5800 Nyborg  17 timer 52 m
10.99            Vestvejen 95 6200 Aabenraa  17 timer 52 m
10.99     Gammel Århusvej 3 8940 Randers SV  17 timer 52 m
10.99   Frederiksværksgade 87 3400 Hillerød  17 timer 52 m
10.99        Egelundsvej 5 2620 Albertslund  17 timer 52 m
10.99         Bøsbrovej 92B 8940 Randers SV  17 timer 52 m
10.99           Milnersvej 47 3400 Hillerød  17 timer 52 m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for remove `Unnamed` columns [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) for boolean mask with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')]
```

And if necessary for remove `NaN`s in all column data use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)
```

Comment: dears, i've put added all codes inside my code, but it seem not work, anyway, thanks for your replied, thanks !

Comment: Hmm, it seems you forget `df = pd.read_html(lines[0])[0]` last `[0]`, also `print type(df)` return `DataFrame` ?

Comment: dears, thanks, but I cannot delete NaN, use dropna , thanks a lot !